# iPhone - Bike physics game

Tags: iphone, physics

I want to make a game where you ride a bicycle down a hill - using accelerometer for rider tilt and a pedal/brake button (vaguely like Moto X Meyhem).

Does any one have any ideas where i can find tutorials/documentation of the things that i would have to do. (don't know where to start)

I guess what i need is: To simulate physics of the bike (inertia & tilt of rider), figure out how the bike interacts with the terrain (ie friction & acceleration), and how to store the information of the actual surface of the terrain.

Could i use Cocos2d and Chipmunk? Any pointers, ideas, suggestions? Any help is appreciated and thanks very much in advanced.

Comment: Could you give more details about what level of programming/mathematical competency is at. It would allow people to pitch their answers to what kind of advice you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a simpler physics based project first.  You will never find that you've done too easy a project.  Do a simple bouncing ball game first - down a hill, into buckets.  You'll have a lot of the physics issues under control when you later go to the bicycle game.  There are only so many problems that you'll want to deal with at one time.

Cocos2d or Unity are great starting points.

Look forward to your games!

Comment: Thanks, i've actually started using Box2d + Cocos2d - it's been working out well

Answer (score 0):

Go to the cocos2d page and download all the examples. Run through them until you understand them.

If this is your first programming task, then you have bitten off a lot.